# Can't start up vagrant box with libvirt as a provider

Tags: vagrant, libvirt

I'm trying to start up vagrant box with libvirt as a provider but i can't.

I'm getting the following error. Name .at_default of domain about to create is already taken. Please try to run vagrant up command again.

I've tried to unistall and reinstall vagrant but didn't help.